# PostgreSQL export/import in Google cloud: issues with roles and users

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I am running this command

```
gcloud sql import sql db1 gs://mybucket/sqldumpfile.gz --database=mydb1
```

to import a database snapshot into a new database. Before running it, I recreated the same users I had in the source database, using Cloud Console. However, I keep on getting this error:

```
ERROR: must be member of role "postgres"
STATEMENT:  ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES  TO user1;
```

I am not sure what to do and which user must be "member of role postgres".

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: The error refers to the user running the query, so the user `gcloud sql import` uses by default when connecting to `db1`. I typically use plain `pg_dump`/`pg_restore`/`psql` to import/export on gcloud so I'm not sure what this default is.

Comment: Hm I did experiment with `gcloud sql import` using user `postgres` but iirc I got another (but similar error). Is it possible to use pg_dump with google cloud storage buckets?

Comment: It is: `pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres | gsutil cp - gs://my_bucket/postgres_dumps/my_dump.sql`. But I think you need the other direction: `gsutil cp gs://my_bucket/postgres_dumps/my_dump.sql -| psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres`

Answer (score 0):

**To grant default privileges for user2, use the FOR ROLE clause:**

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER <user-1> IN SCHEMA <user-1> GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO <user-2>;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER <user-1> IN SCHEMA <user-1> GRANT SELECT  ON TABLES TO <user-2>;
```

You need to grant the rights from the user-1  which is creating the table, So whenever the user-1 creates a table, it will grant the SELECT rights for the user-2.

For more information refer to this [document.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)